How to fix a horizontal scroll section with scrollTrigger
I'm trying to have a section that scrolls horizontally while you scroll down. I was looking at videos on how to do this, and although it seems simple enough, i cant get it to work. Can somebody help me understand what I'm doing wrong?
(it looks ugly on code pen because it doesn't have my local files and the rest of the CSS. Just what's  necessary)
Here is my code on CodePen
This is an example of what I wanted
I tried variations of two ways i saw:
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger)

let sections = gsap.utils.toArray('.card-scroller div')

gsap.to(sections, {
    xPercent: -100 * (sections.length - 1),
    scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: (".card-scroller"),
        pin: true,
        scrub: 1,
        end: "+=3000"
    }
})

From this YT Video
and
From this YT Video
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger)
});

const container = document.querySelector('.card-scroller')
const sections = gsap.utils.toArray('.card-scroller div')


let scrollTween = gsap.to(sections, {
    xPercent: -100 * (sections.length - 1),
    ease: "none",
    scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: (".card-scroller"),
        pin: true,
        scrub: 1,
        end: "+=3000"
    }
})                         


Welcome to StackOverflow! Hmmm, if you have a CodePen that seems to work just the way you want, what specifically is the issue?

Have you seen console errors in your codepen, add https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/gsap-latest-beta.min.js?r=5426, https://assets.codepen.io/16327/ScrollTrigger.min.js, https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/7ba936b34824fefdccfe2c6d9f0b740b.js in settings of js>Add External Scripts

@Leland it doesn't work on my end. There are 3 cards that should pass horizontally in a carousel type motion (scrolling horizontally)

@redoc I didn't get any console errors until i added those links. the error that appeared was "Uncaught ReferenceError: ScrollTrigger is not defined"

those are previous error, you have to clear console, see my edited: https://codepen.io/soredoc/pen/gOVoNpO ik it is not proper,but to mention that you have to add https://assets.codepen.io/16327/ScrollTrigger.min.js to make it atleast scroll horizontally

@redoc wow, that was simple. Thank you! I see that that is a direct codepen link. Will that work on an independent website? one thats not on codepen

Yes the assets.codepen.io link will work, though you can see if the code is hosted somewhere and may use,or download the file and use yourself.
